# How to develop linux screen saver

Tags: linux, screensaver

Does anyone have a link or document on how to write a screensaver for Linux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's some info on xscreensaver that you may find of use: [xscreensaver](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~liberato/screensaver/)
also there's an FAQ [here](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#writing-savers).

There's a simple tutorial here too: [simplesquares](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~liberato/screensaver/simplesquares.html) (from the first link)

Answer (score 8):

This might be of interest to you:

http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#writing-savers

it's from the xscreensavers homepage, it's sort of the de facto screensaver

Answer (score 0):

Google "xscreensaver", and you can learn from its code, rather than starting from scratch.