# Xscreensaver renders nothing

Tags: c, linux, x11

I try to make a screensaver for Linux based on "simplesquares" from: http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~liberato/screensaver/simplesquares.html

I overcome the compile errors ([gcc - errors compiling example xscreensaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522228/gcc-errors-compiling-example-xscreensaver)), but after running the compiled file, nothing is shown at all. No matter if run inside Eclipse or the command line. Currently, my code is exaclty the one from the first link.
My environement: Ubuntu 15.04 x86, Mate 1.8.2, gcc 4.9.2, libx11-dev 2:1.6.2.

What changes do i have to make to the code of `simplesquares.c` (and maybe `vroot.h`) in order make it show something?

The user here [Hints and tips for writing a screensaver using xscreensaver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686699/hints-and-tips-for-writing-a-screensaver-using-xscreensaver) has the same problem with the missing output, but there is no answer and the question was closed because of other reasons.

Comment: You can't see anything because the code draws on the root window which is normally obscured by the desktop. Try running it as a part of xscreensaver as intended. Alternatively, run another X11 server without any desktop environment and preferably with no window manager, and try running your program there.

Comment: You are right, please convert it to an answer :) Here http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man1.html under "programs (class Programs)" is shown how to add your binary to xscreensavers list.